# How to create a view over a range that always picks the first element and filters the rest?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I have a collection of values:

```
auto v = std::vector{43, 1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 19, 101};
```

Over this collection of values I want to apply a view that follows this criteria:

- First element should always be picked.
- From the next elements, pick only even numbers until ...
- ... finding an element equal or greater than 6.

This is the view I tried:

```
auto v = std::vector{43, 1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 19, 101};
auto r = v |
    std::views::take(1) |
    std::views::filter([](const int x) { return !(x & 1); }) |
    std::views::take_while([](const int x) { return x < 6; });

for (const auto &x : r)
    std::cout << x << ' ';
```

But the execution don't even enter the print loop because the view is empty. My guess si that all the criteria is applied at once:

1. Pick first element (43).
2. Is odd number.
3. View ends.

What I was expecting:

1. Pick first element without checking anything.
2. From the rest of elements, filter only even numbers (`2`, `4`, `6`, `8`).
3. From filtered elements, pick numbers until a number equal to or greater than 6 appears (`2`, `4`).
4. `43 2 4` is printed.

How can I build a view over my collection of values that behaves as I was expecting?

Comment: Build it into filter (or concatenate `take(1)` and the rest).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you can use `views::concat` to concatenate the first element of the range and the remaining filtered elements, for example:

```
auto v = std::vector{43, 1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 19, 101};
auto r = ranges::views::concat(
  v | ranges::views::take(1),
  v | ranges::views::drop(1)
    | ranges::views::filter([](const int x) { return !(x & 1); })
    | ranges::views::take_while([](const int x) { return x < 6; })
);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TrKMsajf8)

Answer (score 2):

Edit: My first solution will not work, as correctly pointed out by
康桓瑋

```
bool first = true;
auto r = v |
    std::views::filter([first](const int x) { return first || !(x & 1); }) |
    std::views::take_while([&first](const int x) { return std::exchange(first, false) || x < 6; });
```

It seems to work with two bool variables, one for filter and one for take_while, but not sure if it is really ub or not, e.g:

```
bool firstWhile = true;
bool firstTake = true;
auto r = v |
    std::views::filter([&firstWhile](const int x) { return std::exchange(firstWhile, false) || !(x & 1); }) |
    std::views::take_while([&firstTake](const int x) { return std::exchange(firstTake, false) || x < 6; });
```

So I make a new suggestion which avoids the problems, though it is dependent upon std::views::zip, which comes with C++23, or range-v3, which is (assuming `using namespace std::views` for simplicity):

```
auto r = zip(iota(0), v) | 
    filter([](const auto& it) { return it.first == 0 || !(it.second & 1); }) |
    take_while([](const auto& it) { return it.first == 0 || it.second < 6; }) |
    transform([](const auto& it) { return it.second; });
```

[Demo:](https://godbolt.org/z/f75jqTvYh)

Not sure I like the complexity of either this or the other solution given, but there you have it.

Comment: This will gives `[43, 1, 3, 2, 4]`, which is not what the OP asked for. Also, your lambda does not satisfy [`regular_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/invocable), so this is undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that the value_type of `zip::iterator` is no longer pair since [P2165](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2165r4.pdf), so you may need to use `std::get<0>` instead of `.first`.